# Grafana alert/notifier not showing in contact points

Tags: notifications, kubernetes-helm, alert, grafana

I'm currently setting up a new Grafana with the latest version and helm chart.
I added a notifier so alerts are send to a microsoft teams channel.
The notifiers.yaml can be found in the running container in 'etc/grafana/provisioning/notifiers'

Unfortunately it does not appear in 'contact points'.

The part of the helm chart regarding notfiers looks like this

```
notifiers: 
 notifiers.yaml:
   notifiers:
   - name: sa-roemoe-notifier
     type: teams
     uid: lnc31CJGz
     org_id: 1
     is_default: true
     settings:
       url: <<myTeamsUrl>>
```

Is there something wrong with it?
Since it already is in the running container I assume I made a mistake but I can't figure it out.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Also faced with such problem after migrating to new alerting in grafana 9.

try another way

```
alerting:
  contactpoints.yaml:
    apiVersion: 1
    contactPoints:
      - orgId: 1
        name: Name
        receivers:
          - uid: Name
            type: webhook
            settings:
              url: https://url
              ....
```

Comment: this worked for me in Grafana 9.5.2 as well - utter lifesaver