# Grafana alert provisioning issue

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-api

I'd like to be able to provision alerts, and try to follow [this instructions](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/set-up/provision-alerting-resources/file-provisioning/#provision-alert-rules), but no luck!

OS Grafana version: 9.2.0 Running in Kubernetes

Steps that I take:

1. Created a new alert rule from UI.
2. Extract alert rule from API:
   `curl -k https://<my-grafana-url>/api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules/-4pMuQFVk -u admin:<my-admin-password>`

It returns the following:

```
---
id: 18
uid: "-4pMuQFVk"
orgID: 1
folderUID: 3i72aQKVk
ruleGroup: cpu_alert_group
title: my_cpu_alert
condition: B
data:
- refId: A
  queryType: ''
  relativeTimeRange:
    from: 600
    to: 0
  datasourceUid: _SaubQF4k
  model:
    editorMode: code
    expr: system_cpu_usage
    hide: false
    intervalMs: 1000
    legendFormat: __auto
    maxDataPoints: 43200
    range: true
    refId: A
- refId: B
  queryType: ''
  relativeTimeRange:
    from: 0
    to: 0
  datasourceUid: "-100"
  model:
    conditions:
    - evaluator:
        params:
        - 3
        type: gt
      operator:
        type: and
      query:
        params:
        - A
      reducer:
        params: []
        type: last
      type: query
    datasource:
      type: __expr__
      uid: "-100"
    expression: A
    hide: false
    intervalMs: 1000
    maxDataPoints: 43200
    refId: B
    type: classic_conditions
updated: '2022-12-07T20:01:47Z'
noDataState: NoData
execErrState: Error
for: 5m
```

3. Deleted the alert rule from UI.
4. Made a configmap from above alert-rule, as such:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana-alerting
data:
  alerting.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    groups:
      - id: 18
        uid: "-4pMuQFVk"
        orgID: 1
        folderUID: 3i72aQKVk
        ruleGroup: cpu_alert_group
        title: my_cpu_alert
        condition: B
        data:
        - refId: A
          queryType: ''
          relativeTimeRange:
            from: 600
            to: 0
          datasourceUid: _SaubQF4k
          model:
            editorMode: code
            expr: system_cpu_usage
            hide: false
            intervalMs: 1000
            legendFormat: __auto
            maxDataPoints: 43200
            range: true
            refId: A
        - refId: B
          queryType: ''
          relativeTimeRange:
            from: 0
            to: 0
          datasourceUid: "-100"
          model:
            conditions:
            - evaluator:
                params:
                - 3
                type: gt
              operator:
                type: and
              query:
                params:
                - A
              reducer:
                params: []
                type: last
              type: query
            datasource:
              type: __expr__
              uid: "-100"
            expression: A
            hide: false
            intervalMs: 1000
            maxDataPoints: 43200
            refId: B
            type: classic_conditions
        updated: '2022-12-07T20:01:47Z'
        noDataState: NoData
        execErrState: Error
        for: 5m
```

I mount above configmap in grafana container (in `/etc/grafna/provisioning/alerting`).
The full manifest of the deployment is as follow:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: grafana
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: monitoring
  creationTimestamp: "2022-12-08T18:31:30Z"
  generation: 4
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 9.3.0
    helm.sh/chart: grafana-6.46.1
  name: grafana
  namespace: monitoring
  resourceVersion: "648617"
  uid: dc06b802-5281-4f31-a2b2-fef3cf53a70b
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: grafana
      app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 98cac51656714db48a116d3109994ee48c401b138bc8459540e1a497f994d197
        checksum/dashboards-json-config: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
        checksum/sc-dashboard-provider-config: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c05124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
        checksum/secret: 203f0e4d883461bdd41fe68515fc47f679722dc2fdda49b584209d1d288a5f07
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: grafana
        app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: admin-user
              name: grafana
        - name: GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: admin-password
              name: grafana
        - name: GF_PATHS_DATA
          value: /var/lib/grafana/
        - name: GF_PATHS_LOGS
          value: /var/log/grafana
        - name: GF_PATHS_PLUGINS
          value: /var/lib/grafana/plugins
        - name: GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING
          value: /etc/grafana/provisioning
        image: grafana/grafana:9.3.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /api/health
            port: 3000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 30
        name: grafana
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: grafana
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /api/health
            port: 3000
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
          name: config
          subPath: grafana.ini
        - mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/alerting
          name: grafana-alerting
        - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
          name: storage
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      enableServiceLinks: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 472
        runAsGroup: 472
        runAsUser: 472
      serviceAccount: grafana
      serviceAccountName: grafana
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: grafana-alerting
        name: grafana-alerting
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: grafana
        name: config
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: storage
```

However, grafana fail to start with this error:

`Failed to start grafana. error: failure to map file alerting.yaml: failure parsing rules: rule group has no name set`

I fixed above error by adding Group Name, but similar errors about other missing elements kept showing up again and again (to the point that I stopped chasing, as I couldn't figure out what exactly the correct schema is). Digging in, it looks like the format/schema returned from API in step 2, is different than the schema that's pointed out [in the documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/set-up/provision-alerting-resources/file-provisioning/#provision-alert-rules).

Why is the schema of the alert-rule returned from API different? Am I supposed to convert it, and if so how? Otherwise, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: Replaced Statefulset with deployment, since I was able to reproduce this in a normal/minimal Grafana deployment too.

Answer (score 0):

Additional endpoints were added to the Grafana provisioning API in v9.4.0 to support exporting alert rules in the correct format to then provision them via the API. These were added by [this PR](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/58623)

The new endpoints are as follows:

```
/api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules/export
/api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules/{UID}/export
/api/v1/provisioning/folder/{FolderUID}/rule-groups/{Group}/export
```